# How would I save time with or statements in Python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a AI program in Python and want to save time when interacting with the bot. Instead of using this code:

```
if "how are you" or "How are you" in talk:
     perform_action()
```

I want to be able to interpret it even if it's not capitalize or not. If you don't what I'm saying let's say I asked the bot, "how are you?", but the bot was only programmed to answer to that question if it was said like this, "How are you?". I want to simplify the coding so I won't have to use a "or" statement. Please provide example code.

Comment: Is this homework? try looking at `talk.lower()`

Comment: It's really important to note that the code you wrote above, as written, will not work as you expect it to. It will *always* evaluate to True, and perform_action() will always be called. The conditional can be parsed as [if ("how are you") or ("How are you" in talk):], which always returns true, because "how are you" evaluates to true. What you want is probably [if "how are you" in talk or "How are you" in talk:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if talk.upper() == "HOW ARE YOU":
    perform_action()
```

or, if you prefer to search for substrings

```
if "HOW ARE YOU" in talk.upper():
    perform_action()
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way would be to lowercase everything:

```
if "how are you" == talk.lower():
```

Comment: You should [normalize to uppercase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386042.aspx).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi since they won't be needing to be converted back, I don't see a reason to, although I could be reading it wrong